# How to test the Solidity fallback() function via Hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, rsk

I have a Solidity smart contract `Demo` which I am developing in [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/) and testing on the [RSK Testnet](https://developers.rsk.co/rsk/public-nodes/).

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Demo {
    event Error(string);
    fallback() external {
      emit Error("call of a non-existent function");
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that the `fallback` function is called and the event `Error` is emitted. To this end, I am trying to call a `nonExistentFunction` on the smart contract:

```js
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { ethers } = require('hardhat');

describe('Demo', () => {
  let deployer;
  let demoContract;
    
  before(async () => {
    [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const factory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Demo');
    demoContract = await factory.deploy().then((res) => res.deployed());
  });
    
  it('should invoke the fallback function', async () => {
    const tx = demoContract.nonExistentFunction();
    await expect(tx)
      .to.emit(demoContract, 'Error')
      .withArgs('call of a non-existent function');
  });
});
```

However Hardhat throws a `TypeError` even before it actually connects to the smart contract on RSK:

```
  Demo
    1) should invoke the fallback function


  0 passing (555ms)
  1 failing

  1) Demo
       should invoke the fallback function:
     TypeError: demoContract.nonExistentFunction is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/Demo.js:13:29)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

How can I outsmart Hardhat/Ethers.js and finally be able to call non-existent function thus invoking the `fallback` function in the smart contract?

For reference, this is my `hardhat.config.js`

```js
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
const { mnemonic } = require('./.secret.json');

module.exports = {
  solidity: '0.8.4',
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    rsktestnet: {
      chainId: 31,
      url: 'https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/',
      accounts: {
        mnemonic,
        path: "m/44'/60'/0'/0",
      },
    },
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 600000,
  },
};
```

Comment: Initialise an `ethers.Contract` instance with a modified ABI that includes a function signature that does not exist in the actual contract. With thatyou should be able to write this test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the approach of injecting a non-existent function signature
into the smart contract object (`ethers.Contract`).
Create a function *signature* for `nonExistentFunction`:

```js
const nonExistentFuncSignature =
  'nonExistentFunction(uint256,uint256)';
```

Note that the parameter list should contain no whitespace,
and consists of parameter types only (no parameter names).

Then instantiate a new smart contract object.

When you do this you need to modify the ABI for `Demo`
such that it includes this additional function signature.:

```js
const fakeDemoContract = new ethers.Contract(
  demoContract.address,
  [
    ...demoContract.interface.fragments,
    `function ${nonExistentFuncSignature}`,
  ],
  deployer,
);
```

Note that the contract that is deployed is the same as before -
it does **not** contain this new function.
However the client interacting with this smart contract -
the tests in this case -
does *think* that the smart contract has this function now.

At this point, you'll be able to run your original test,
with a minor modification:

```js
const tx = fakeDemoContract[nonExistentFuncSignature](8, 9);
await expect(tx)
  .to.emit(demoContract, 'Error')
  .withArgs('call of a non-existent function');
```

---

Full test:

```js
it('should invoke the fallback function', async () => {
    const nonExistentFuncSignature = 'nonExistentFunc(uint256,uint256)';
    const fakeDemoContract = new ethers.Contract(
      demoContract.address,
      [
        ...demoContract.interface.fragments,
        `function ${nonExistentFuncSignature}`,
      ],
      deployer,
    );
    const tx = fakeDemoContract[nonExistentFuncSignature](8, 9);
    await expect(tx)
      .to.emit(demoContract, 'Error')
      .withArgs('call of a non-existent function');
 });
```

Test result:

```
  Demo
    ✔ should invoke the fallback function (77933ms)


  1 passing (2m)
```

Answer (score 4):

A transaction executing a function contains the function [selector](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/abi-spec.html#function-selector) following its (ABI-encoded) input params in the `data` field.

The `fallback()` function gets executed when the transaction `data` field starts with a selector that does not match any existing function. For example an empty selector.

So you can generate a transaction `to` the contract address, with empty `data` field, which invokes the `fallback()` function.

```
it('should invoke the fallback function', async () => {
    const tx = deployer.sendTransaction({
        to: demoContract.address,
        data: "0x",
    });
    await expect(tx)
        .to.emit(demoContract, 'Error')
        .withArgs('call of a non-existent function');
});
```

---

*Note: If you also declared the [receive()](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/contracts.html#receive-ether-function) function, it takes precedence over `fallback()` in case of empty data field. However, `fallback()` still gets executed for every non-empty mismatching selector, while `receive()` is only invoked when the selector is empty.*

Comment: Thanks, I tried your idea, but indeed, If I add the `receive` function to the s/c, it intercepts the `fallback` call. I would like to have a better solution

Comment: @AleksShenshin If you want to invoke the `fallback()` function while having both `fallback()` and `receive()` declared in the contract, you can pass a non-empty `data` value that does not translate to any function selector. For example: `0x1234`.